# concatenate values in dataframe if a column has specific values and None or Null values

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with name+address/email information based on the type. Based on a type I want to concat name+address or name+email into a new column (concat_name) within the dataframe. Some of the types are null and are causing ambiguity errors. Identifying the nulls correctly in place is where I'm having trouble.

```
NULL = None
data = {
    'Type': [NULL, 'MasterCard', 'Visa','Amex'],
    'Name': ['Chris','John','Jill','Mary'],
    'City': ['Tustin','Cleveland',NULL,NULL ],
    'Email': [NULL,NULL,'jdoe@yahoo.com','mdoe@aol.com']
}

df_data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
#Expected resulting df column:
df_data['concat_name'] = ['ChrisTustin', 'JohnCleveland','Jilljdoe@yahoo.com,'Marymdoe@aol.com']
```

**Attempt one using booleans**

```
if df_data['Type'].isnull() | df_data[df_data['Type'] == 'Mastercard':
   df_data['concat_name'] = df_data['Name']+df_data['City']
if df_data[df_data['Type'] == 'Visa' | df_data[df_data['Type'] == 'Amex':
   df_data['concat_name'] = df_data['Name']+df_data['Email']
else:
   df_data['concat_name'] = 'Error'
```

***Error***

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

**Attempt two using np.where**

```
df_data['concat_name'] = np.where((df_data['Type'].isna()|(df_data['Type']=='MasterCard'),df_data['Name']+df_data['City'],
np.where((df_data['Type']=="Visa")|(df_data['Type]=="Amex"),df_data['Name']+df_data['Email'], 'Error'
```

***Error***

```
ValueError: Length of values(2) does not match length of index(12000)
```

Comment: You cannot use `|` operator in `if` loop.

Comment: I changed that portion but am still getting the error of ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following code solve your use case?

```py
# == Imports needed ===========================
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# == Example Dataframe =========================
df_data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Type": [None, "MasterCard", "Visa", "Amex"],
        "Name": ["Chris", "John", "Jill", "Mary"],
        "City": ["Tustin", "Cleveland", None, None],
        "Email": [None, None, "jdoe@yahoo.com", "mdoe@aol.com"],
        # Expected output:
        "concat_name": [
            "ChrisTustin",
            "JohnCleveland",
            "Jilljdoe@yahoo.com",
            "Marymdoe@aol.com",
        ],
    }
)

# == Solution Implementation ====================
df_data["concat_name2"] = np.where(
    (df_data["Type"].isin(["MasterCard", pd.NA, None])),
    df_data["Name"].astype(str).replace("None", "")
    + df_data["City"].astype(str).replace("None", ""),
    np.where(
        (df_data["Type"].isin(["Visa", "Amex"])),
        df_data["Name"].astype(str).replace("None", "")
        + df_data["Email"].astype(str).replace("None", ""),
        "Error",
    ),
)
# == Expected Output ============================
print(df_data)
# Prints:
#          Type   Name       City           Email         concat_name          concat_name2
# 0        None  Chris     Tustin            None         ChrisTustin           ChrisTustin
# 1  MasterCard   John  Cleveland            None       JohnCleveland         JohnCleveland
# 2        Visa   Jill       None  jdoe@yahoo.com  Jilljdoe@yahoo.com    Jilljdoe@yahoo.com
# 3        Amex   Mary       None    mdoe@aol.com    Marymdoe@aol.com      Marymdoe@aol.com
```

### Notes

You might also consider simplifying the problem, by replacing the first condition (`Type == 'MasterCard' or None`) with the opposite of your second condition (`Type == 'Visa' or 'Amex'`):

```py
df_data["concat_name2"] = np.where(
    (~df_data["Type"].isin(["Visa", "Amex"])),
    df_data["Name"].astype(str).replace("None", "")
    + df_data["City"].astype(str).replace("None", ""),
    df_data["Name"].astype(str).replace("None", "")
    + df_data["Email"].astype(str).replace("None", "")
)
```

Additionally, if you are dealing with messy data, you can also improve the implementation by converting the `Type` column to lowercase, or uppercase. This    makes your code also account for cases where you have values like `"mastercard", or "Mastercard", etc.`:

```py
df_data["concat_name2"] = np.where(
    (df_data["Type"].astype(str).str.lower().isin(["mastercard", pd.NA, None, "none"])),
    df_data["Name"].astype(str).replace("None", "")
    + df_data["City"].astype(str).replace("None", ""),
    np.where(
        (df_data["Type"].astype(str).str.lower().isin(["visa", "amex"])),
        df_data["Name"].astype(str).replace("None", "")
        + df_data["Email"].astype(str).replace("None", ""),
        "Error",
    ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked, with just one change. I had to replace `pd.NA` with `np.NaN`  since that's what my data contained. Thanks again.